# s3 presign url between s3 buckets using Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, pre-signed-url

hope all is well. I am trying to upload a file that is situated in my s3 bucket to another bucket. However, I want to  use a lambda function to upload it to another bucket using s3 presign URL as I want it to have an expiration feature in the new bucket. I passed the object file URL as key when uploading to destination bucket but does not seem to work. Some guidance would be appreciated.

```
import json
import time
import boto3

s3= boto3.client('s3')

  time.sleep(10)   
    bucket_name_file='mybucketname'
    
    #fetch last modified item from bucket
    response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name2)
    all = response2['Contents']        
    latest = max(all, key=lambda x: x['LastModified'])
    my_file_name=latest['Key']
 
    url_of_my_filename='https://'+bucket_name_file+'.s3.amazonaws.com/'+my_file_name
    
    

    ###################################################
    destination_bucket_to_send='my_destination_bucket'
    
    url=s3_client.generate_presigned_url('put_object',
                              Params={'Bucket': destination_bucket,
                                      'Key':url_of_my_filename,
                                      
                              },
                              ExpiresIn=20000)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want it to have an expiration feature in the new bucket"? It is not possible to store an object in Amazon S3 with an expiration date. A pre-signed URL provides temporary access to an object, but objects are not 'stored' with an expiration date.

Comment: I want to upload an existing s3 file to another bucket using s3 presign URL so that I can provide temporary access to the new object in the new bucket using a lmbda function@JohnRotenstein

Comment: I see the expiration is 200 seconds. Could it be that the link expired before it got the chance to be used? You can try to change that to be longer.

Also, if your goal is to limit the time people can access the file, you will need to specify that when you generate the access url(the GET url). The upload url's expiration only limits the the time the upload url can be used.

Comment: @BemTG I am still quite confused. Why are you wanting to copy the object to a different bucket rather than simply providing a pre-signed URL that points to the object in the _existing_ bucket?

Comment: What @JohnRotenstein says makes sense for the use case you are describing. If you really NEED to upload, it might help us help you if you also post the upload code.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I do not want to complicate this issue further but it is due the file being an output file from a transcription job. amazon transcriptions do not have an expiry feature when they are sent over to your desired bucket. Hence I am trying to copy them over using  presign URL

Comment: Objects in Amazon S3 do _not_ have an expiry feature. You can generate a pre-signed URL, and that URL will expire after a given period, but objects themselves do not 'expire'. There is no concept of "copying an object using a pre-signed URL". What is the end-goal that you actually wanting to accomplish (as opposed to _how_)?

Comment: the end goal is to generate a new presign URL in another bucket by pointing to an existing s3 file . @JohnRotenstein

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I want the output transcription files to be presigned URL however, as I said before Amazon transcription seem not support this

Comment: @BemTG in the code you posted, you are generating the presigned url. Can you also share the code where you are using that url(the PUT)?

Comment: @BemTG You will always need to create your own Presigned URL. However, as per my answer below, you will be able to create it based on the object created by Amazon Translate. Have you tried this? There should be no need to copy or upload any files. A pre-signed URL can point to _any_ object in Amazon S3. It is simply a way to provide temporary access to a private S3 object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that your goal is to use Amazon Translate to translate some text via a Transcription Job. You then want to offer the resulting translation via a temporary URL.

To accomplish this, you can create an Amazon S3 pre-signed URL on the object that was created by the transcription job. This URL can then be used from the Internet to obtain the translation. Once the expiry period has passed, the URL will no longer provide access to the object.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what the issue was.